# Can I ask for feedback on an idea for a standard?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm looking to come up with a **standard for how to implement a system that will automatically update software**. As such, there is no actual programming per se, but I still want to make sure my standard is robust before moving on to the stage where I build a proof-of-concept prototype.

I have a good outline of the idea, which is what I would want to be critiqued, but no actual code to review.

**Can I ask for a review of my idea for a standard here?** If so, what do I use as tags? If not, where would be the best place to go for this?

For reference, the idea which I would be posing is [The BARC on GitHub](https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/The-BARC/blob/Refine/Refine.txt).

Comment: The only suggestion I have is to name the file .md rather than .txt then you at least get to use markdown in your file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, this is *Code* Review. We absolutely do require code to be present in the question, and it must be real code, not just example code.

On the programming-related Stack Exchange sites, the progression might look like this:

- “I'm designing a FooBar. How can I introduce frobnication without violating SOLID?”

  Conceptual questions about software development in general and software design and architecture in particular are on-topic for Programmers.
- “I'm implementing a FooBar, but it breaks my frobnication”

  Concrete questions about problems with your code belong on Stack Overflow.
- “How can I improve my working FooBar? I'm especially interested in feedback on frobnication.”

  If you have a working implementation, you can ask here on Code Review on how it could be improved.

So you might be tempted to ask on Programmers for a review of your standard. Unfortunately for you, design reviews don't really fly there, and they'd be closed as “too broad”. However, you can identify and ask specific, limited questions about standards and specifications as well as architecture there. Please see their [on-topic help](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details.

Comment: Thanks! I've [asked again on Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7117/can-i-ask-for-feedback-on-an-idea-for-a-standard).